# kubernetes @ bareMetal: how to deal with DNS?

Tags: networking, dns, kubernetes

I am using a bare-metal kubernetes cluster. Using metalLB loadbalancer in front of ingress-nginx.

I have no background in DNS services.
I know we have some DNS-server running in the datacenter. What is the best practice that services populated by ingress-nginx are resolvable by clients which are using the datacenter's DNS service?

Example:
In ingress I have configured the host "app1.myownKubernetesCluster.internal"
metalLB is assigning the the IP 192.168.1.20 for the ingress controller.

I want to be able to resolve app1.myownKubernetesCluster.internal to 192.168.1.20 from a client which is using the datacenter's DNS-server.

What is the best practice for that? Is there some kind of DNS forwarding?

Thanks, Andreas